Not able to convert lead into an existing Account, existing contact with no Opportunity
The user is trying to convert a lead into an existing account, and an existing contact with no opportunity being created upon conversion(Don't create an opportunity upon conversion box is checked).
Error on UI : There was an error converting the lead. Please try again. If the problem persists, please contact your administrator.
Upon debugging : There is an after-save record triggered flow on the contact object, that gets triggered when a contact record is created or updated.
What essentially the flow is doing is updating few fields on the same contact record that triggered this flow to run.
Flow fails to update the contact record as a result of which everything gets rolled back, lead is not getting converted, showing up an error in the UI.
Error Occurred : The flow tried to update these records: 0038aXXXXXXXXX. This error occurred: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "common.udd.FieldInfo.getFieldId()" because the return value of "common.udd.EntityInfo.getPrimaryKeyField()" is null. You can look up Exception Code values in the SOAP API Developer Guide.
Salesforce Error ID: 1840485789-18718(1209753213)
I have tried replicating the same thing in lower environment, it works fine, lead is getting converted, but the same thing in prod is not happening.
Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

In general, GACKs require getting SFDC Support involved. If it works in a "lower" environment but not PROD, try changing the API version of the Flow to something V61 or earlier to see if that helps

we are already using V58.
